# Trouble getting desired response issuing a post requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get a `200` status code issuing a post http requests but when I run my script I get `403` instead. It seems that I followed the way how the requests is being sent in chrome dev tools.

To do it manually - go to that page, select `6` as size and then hit the `add to cart` button.

***How can I do the same using the script below?***

[Webpage address](https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/nike-signal-dmsx-men-shoes-73190?v=314207586604#!searchCategory=men/shoes/running)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_url = 'https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/homepage'
post_url = 'https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/addtocart?'

params = {
    'SynchronizerToken': '',
    'Ajax': True,
    'Relay42_Category': 'Product Pages',
    'acctab-tabgroup-314207586604090': None,
    'Quantity_314207586604070': '1',
    'SKU': '314207586604070'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(main_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    #parsing token to reuse within data
    token = soup.select_one("[name='SynchronizerToken']")['value']

    params['SynchronizerToken'] = token

    res = s.post(post_url,params=params,data=params,headers={
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'referer': 'https://www.footlocker.co.uk/en/p/nike-signal-dmsx-men-shoes-73190?v=314207586604',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
        })
    print(res.status_code)
```

Current status:

```
403
```

Expected status:

```
200
```

Comment: I ran your code and got a 200 status code. Also, a 403 status code is forbidden, so your ip could be temporarily blocked for a number of reasons (too many requests, etc.)

Comment: Wrong!! I use vpn and I use them rotatioally. Moreover, I test it elsewhere but the status is always 403. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt They are probably blocking your vpn provider or have some kind of request limit.  I tried your code and got a 200 as well.

Comment: I tested the OP's code and I received a 403 on the first try, so it's unlikely the OP's IP addresses is being blocked.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I'm assuming you tested it using your home IP address and that you live in the US?  You getting a 403 on the first try is contrary to my answer...

Comment: @CalebGoodman Nope, I'm using a VPN, which is configured with a UK address. Is there another way to test the OP's code?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I tested it using my home IP in the US and didn't get a 403 (at first).

Comment: Your VPN being blocked confirms my answer more than anything; they are blocking certain VPN providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and got a 200 response, so I ran your code again in a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get(main_url)

...
```

And after the 8th call, I started receiving 403 responses (IE permission denied).

You said you were using a vpn, but it looks like they either ban certain vpn providers, or you are hitting the request limit with a given IP without realizing it.

I assume the former, since I tested your code using tor and also got a 403.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works.
Received 200.

403 fobidden means

```
Client : Give me your data
Server: Nope
```

If you have got 200 status code before, more likely you 
have been blocked.

Another possibility is that the server side service logic has been modified to protect themselves, in this case, no one can access, but the server itself can internally. 
**But this won't be the case as I got 200.**

**Each server has own policy to protect itself.**
Some blocks temporarily, some blocks permanently.

Here what you can try,

**1. Change User-Agent**
Sometime server blocks certain browser which requests too much. Use the latest version of different browsers.

**2. Change your IP**
(Of course changed IP can be blocked)

**3. Increase your request interval**

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code, and it looks perfect. Actually, It's not your code's fault. It's from website. After testing your code, I go through the website and tested it manually. And I found that the side will be `disabled` `Add to cart` button if you continuously try to hit the `Add to cart` button around 5-8 times. So, you need to think in that way. Your code is perfect.