# Scraping from site that requires login, how to access the contents?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to scrape a website that requires a login. I have used requests and submitted my login details, although when I try to extract the data from the website, I am not getting the website I am looking for.

```
USERNAME = "test@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "test"
#MIDDLEWARE_TOKEN = "TESTTOKEN"
LOGIN_URL = "https://vrdistribution.com.au/auth/login/process"
VR_URL = "https://vrdistribution.com.au/categories/tabletop-gaming?page=1"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='_token']/@value")))

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "email": USERNAME, 
        "password": PASSWORD, 
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": authenticity_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    #Scrape
    result = session_requests.get(VR_URL, headers =dict(referer=VR_URL))
    response = requests.get(VR_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

The output is not the same contents as the VR_URL(https://vrdistribution.com.au/categories/tabletop-gaming?page=1) that I had specified, when I inspect the page I want to scrape as opposed to the output of the `soup` object, it is completely different.

Is there a way for me to access and scrape contents off the VR_URL?

Comment: Are you sure it will be `csrfmiddlewaretoken` instead of `_token` within `payload`? Moreover, referer should be `https://vrdistribution.com.au/auth/login` . I tried using wrong credentials and this is the variation I could notice.

Comment: @SIM - Yes, I have tried both variations including using `_token` and changing the referrer link, it seems that this still gives the same result, the output remains the same.

Comment: You also missed few important headers to include, as in `user-agent`,`content-type` and `cookie`. You can copy and paste the cookie value from the browser to see how it behaves.

Comment: Sorry I do not really know what you mean by that, could you give me some further guidance?

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57827402/trouble-getting-desired-response-issuing-a-post-requests), not the answer to see how to include multiple headers. Btw, you need to collect those headers from the browser using chrome dev tools or something similar.